# Loop serialized array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

With AJAX I send a serialized array to PHP. The array looks like this

```
Array
(
    ['product1'] => Array
        (
            ['price'] => 12.50
            ['stock'] => onstock
        )

    ['product2'] => Array
        (
            ['price'] => 22.95
            ['stock'] => outofstock
        )

    ['product3'] => Array
        (
            ['price'] => 110.00
            ['stock'] => outofstock
        )
)
```

I looking for a foreach loop and echo the data

```
<?php

$output .= '<div class="price"></div>';//set price here
$output .= '<div class="text">Stockstatus below</div>'
$output .= '<div class="stockstatus"></div>';//set stocks here

echo $output;
?>
```

Who can help me with this?

I tried this

```
<?php
$output = $_GET['products'];
foreach($output as $products => $value){
$price = $value['price'];
$stock = $value['stock'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? Here we expect you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please **attempt something** then update your question to show a **specific** problem you're having in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If you're sending a serialized array, you should first unserialize it before iteration.

Comment: Stefan, your `$output` variable doesn't appear to reference your array at all. Have you tried `$output .= '<div class="price">' . $_GET['product1']['price'] . '</div>';` ?

Answer (score 0):

A few tips:

- If you are sending a serialized array in JSON format, first you need to decode it, since JSON is simply text. For that you can use [json_decode](https://www.php.net/json_decode).
- After decoding it, then you can loop through the decoded array and interpolate the values you want into the HTML string.

I hope it sets you in the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Use `unserialize` and then do it in this way

```
$output = '';
foreach($products as $product){
  $output .= '<div class="price">'.$product["price"].'</div>';
  $output .= '<div class="text">Stockstatus below</div>';
  $output .= '<div class="stockstatus">'.$product["stock"].'</div>';
}
echo $output;
```